# Documenter.jl UndefVarError

Tags: import, julia, undefined, documentation-generation, undefvarerror

I am trying to create a documentation for a Julia module using `Documenter.jl`. Now I imported a module which documenter cannot find for some reason. More explicitly: I imported `SparseArrays.jl` via `import SparseArrays` and am referencing `SparseArrays.AbstractSparseArray` in a docstring. (I also have `SparseArrays.jl` installed.) Yet I get `ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: SparseArrays not defined`. What's the reason and how can I fix this?

EDIT: This is what the relevant parts of the code look like:

```
module ExampleModule
import SparseArrays
include("example.jl")
end
```

`example.jl`:

```
"""
    f
does stuff.
"""
function f(x::SparseArrays.AbstractSparseArray)
    return
end
```

`index.md`:

````
```@docs
f(x::SparseArrays.AbstractSparseArray)
```
````

Comment: To include triple backticks in a markdown code block, use *four* backticks to open and close the block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have imported it in a separate code block. See [here](https://juliadocs.github.io/Documenter.jl/stable/man/doctests/#Preserving-Definitions-Between-Blocks) for an explanation of the issue.

Also you might need to add `import SparseArrays` in setup code as explained [here](https://juliadocs.github.io/Documenter.jl/stable/man/doctests/#Setup-Code). This is needed if e.g. you have doctests inside docstrings.

[Here](https://github.com/JuliaData/DataFrames.jl/blob/eddc3e7871db327d966fcd273583e825fb04450e/docs/make.jl#L5) is an example how it is done in DataFrames.jl (in general DataFrames.jl has doctests enabled both in docstrings and in documentation code so you can have a look at the whole setup we have there).

If this is not the reason then could you please share your code in the question so that it can be inspected?

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you mean. I have imported it at the beginning of the module. It should be useable within a docstring within the module then, no? I'll add the important parts of the code to the question.

Comment: I have added an additional comment - I hope it helps.

Comment: My question wasn't precise I suppose, I am not actually referencing it inside the docstring. I just have a docstring for a function that takes as input an object of that type. And that makes `documenter` throw an error. Do you see anything wrong with my code above?

Comment: This is strange (I assume you have Project.toml properly set up for documenter). I would open an issue in Documenter.jl for this.

Comment: I also just added the relevant code in the `index.md` file. I don't simply have `f` in the @docs environment but `f(x::SparseArrays.AbstractSparseArray)` because I have different versions of `f` with different docstrings. So `SparseArrays` shows up in the `.md` file. Could that cause the problem and if yes how could I solve it?

Comment: I think `Project.toml` is set up correctly but someone else set it up and I'm fairly new to Julia, I'm not really sure what it is supposed to look like.

Comment: ok I figured it out, probably a beginner's mistake, I didn't know I have to add `using SparseArrays` to `make.jl`, I thought it's enough if that's contained in the module file. Thanks for your help though.